# Opening a Text File in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a program that will count the word frequency within a text file that I have created. I have a text file titled `moms_letter.txt` and this is my code:

```
word_count = {}

File.open("moms_letter.txt", "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
        words = line.split(' ').each do |word|
            word_count[word] += 1 if word_count.has_key? word
            word_count[word] = 1 if not word_count.has_key? word
        end
    end
end

puts word_count
```

The problem I am getting is when I go to run the file, I get the error:

```
there is no such file or directory - moms_letter.txt (Errno: : ENOENT)
```

Not quite sure why this is occurring when I have the text file created. 
Any help is appreciated.

I am also newbie in Ruby, so thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 1):

You must be executing your program from outside the directory where your `moms_letter.txt` file resides. You need to use an **absolute path** to open your file. Or, execute your program always from the directory where the `.txt` is. So, instead of using `"moms_letter.txt"` go with `"complete/path/to/file/moms_letter.txt"`.

Comment: I was able to find my file by `File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'moms_letter'), 'r') do |f|`

Comment: Now I am trying to figure out if there is a way to list the frequencies of specific words in order from greatest to least. So basically now it just lists the occurrences of the words as they are within the text file, however, I want them listed based upon occurrences. Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: Great! Much better, your code will be portable that way.

Comment: Sure, just go with `word_count.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse`. If you want a hash, just add `.to_h` method: `word_count.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse.to_h`.

Comment: Would I do this at the end where I do `puts word_count` or somewhere else within my code?

Comment: Yes, add it to `puts word_count`, that way you will print on screen the list. So your last line will be `puts word_count.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse.to_h`.

Comment: I added that and it says that line 12 has an undefined method 'to_h' for #Array: 0x453cc0> (NoMethodError). Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What Ruby version are you running? `to_h` method is available in version 2.1 or higher.

Comment: If you still want a Hash instead of the resulting Array, you could use something like `puts Hash[*word_count.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse.flatten]`, but i recommend upgrading Ruby instead (unless you are tied to your current version).

Comment: @Patrick opening a text file and counting its words are two separate tasks. You should therefore post a separate question regarding the word count.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Ruby too, but have worked with text files a bit recently. It may seem like an obvious question, but is the text file you're trying to open in the same directory as your .rb file? Otherwise you'll need to include the relative path to it.

For troubleshooting sake, try `File.new("temp.txt", "w")` and then `File.open("temp.txt", "r")` to see if that works. Then you'll know if it's an issue with your code or with the txt file you're trying to access.

Also using `File.exists?("moms_letter.txt")` will help you determine whether you can access that file from within your .rb script.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's in the same directory as both files are in the same folder. Maybe that is my problem.

Comment: I did end up figuring that out, but now I am trying to figure out if there is a way to list the frequencies of specific words in order from greatest to least. So basically now it just lists the occurrences of the words, however, I want them listed based upon occurrences. Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: That's a common technical interview whiteboard problem, so I really should have a quick answer ready for you, but I don't. I think the best approach is to create a hash and then iterate through the document and put the word as the key. Then increment the value for each occurrence of the word. Then you can sort the hash by value. Hope that helps!